# PLpgPSQL Function - return string if no results found

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, stored-functions

I have this function for a movie db

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Q10 (partial_title text)
   RETURNS setof text
AS $$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY SELECT
      concat(title, ' has ', count, ' cast and crew')_

   FROM
      total_size
   WHERE
      title ILIKE '%' || partial_title || '%';

END; $$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

I need it to return the string 'No matches found' instead of just 'O rows' when there is no title in my view total_size.

Any ideas? Cheers

Comment: Honestly I think the most elegant solution is to just leave your function as is, and return `null` in the case of an empty result set.  Then, let the caller decide how to handle that (e.g. using `COALESCE`).

Comment: I would but I'll get marked off on my assignment if it doesn't return the string 'No matches found'  :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use a UNION with a NOT EXISTS condition, but I don't think this is worth the effort though.

A PL/pgSQL function is also not needed, `language sql` is enough (and more efficient):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Q10 (partial_title text)
   RETURNS table (title text)
AS 
$$
  with movies as (
    SELECT concat(title, ' has ', count, ' cast and crew')
    FROM total_size
    WHERE title ILIKE '%' || partial_title || '%'
  ) 
  select *
  from movies
  union all
  select 'No matches found'
  where not exists (select * 
                    from movies);
$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: I was thinking of posting think, but thought it not very clean, but +1 anyway to you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I can't think of a better way  (but I do agree, it's feels a bit clunky)